# How to get control objects from directives

Tags: typescript, angular

How to get control objects from directives without appending any attributes to HTML templates?
Because I want to control its validation state.

```
// app.component.html
<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>

// input.directive.ts
export class InputDirective {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.setError();
  }

  private setError(): void {
    // If I can get a control object like this...
    let control: Control = this.control;

    // I can control its validation state.
    control.errors['required'] = true;
  }
}
```